# ExceldataReader.DataSet Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, exceldatareader

I have installed the nuget package exceldatareader and the extension exceldatareader.dataset but when trying to reference it in the using statement it does not recognize it

```
'''
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using FleetManagerComLog.Models;
using ExcelDataReader;
using ExcelDataReader.DataSet;
'''
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62L1c.png)

I have confirmed via the NugetPackage manager that it is installed.

When trying to add it via the using I do get the following options .Core, .Exceptions & .Log but not .DataSet.

/Edit

[Error using .AsDataSet() after using ExcelDataReader has been added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtF5K.png)

/Edit 2

[Image of the Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLxFo.png)

/Edit 3

[Image of csproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCLBT.png)

/Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsDataSet()` is defined in the `ExcelDataReader` namespace, in the `ExcelDataReader.DataSet` package. There's no separate `ExcelDataReader.DataSet` namespace. You only need `using ExcelDataReader` to use `AsDataSet()` :

```
using ExcelDataReader;

...
using var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);

var result = reader.AsDataSet();
```

You *do* have to add the `ExcelDataReader.DataSet` package though

Comment: Okay that's good to know but when trying to user I get the following error 

"IExcelreader does not contain a definition for AsDataSet"

Comment: @Mr-DillinG did actually add the package? What does your `csproj` file look like?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by the csproj file, but I did add a screenshot of my solution explorer where the packages are shown (i dont see ExcelDataReader.DataSet as a seperate package there)

Comment: The `ExcelDataReader.DataSet` package is missing. The `csproj` file is the project file where all PackageReferences are stored. If you double-click on the project node the file will open

Comment: Got it, I have added an image of the csproj file. Can I manually add the reference for the .DataSet package in the csproj file?

Comment: I tried adding it manually and now it is working, thanks for the help :)